# Silverlight json won't serialize

Tags: json, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, datacontractjsonserializer

I have been trying to serialize some json data in Silverlight.  I am using the following code

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(stacks.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, stacks);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

to attempt the serialization.  It does not work. It was the only example I could find that did not produce errors in Visual Studio.  I am passing a list of custom coded objects (stacks).  When I try to view the results I am getting a blank string.  Anyone got some ideas on how to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream cursor is pointing to the end (after everything was written). Add the line "ms.Position = 0;" before creating the StreamReader.