# how to overcome limitation of json in silverlight

Tags: json, silverlight

I am new to silver light.
I want to Serialize A large amount of json data and I use "DataContractJsonSerializer" Class. When data became large an Error was happened!

How can I Overcome to  limitation of json in this class?

Comment: How large is large, and what error happens?

Comment: Show your code, show error.75 000 characters - a small amount of data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight json won't serialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066970/silverlight-json-wont-serialize)